# How can I create a square matrix table in SQL?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a website in Laravel where we have realised that what we want to do is setup a matrix where the rows contain buyer IDs and the columns contain seller IDs. Each user on this website is both a buyer and a seller. And in each (buyer,seller) cell contains the quantity that the buyer has bought from that respective seller. This matrix is ordered so that the buyer on the 7th row is also a seller on the 7th column and it also needs to be dynamic in the sense that a buyer and seller can be added or removed. I'm new to SQL and eloquent so how could I go about creating this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't!**

Use [a many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) on the `Users` table to realize this. You can use a primary key on the table consisting of `buyer_id` and `seller_id` to prevent duplicates. And you can add an extra field to the pivot table to keep track of the quantity.

The database structure of your application should never be changed because of data.

Comment: I'm quite new to Laravel and this 'hasOne' and 'hasMany' syntax is confusing to me. I'll explain my reasoning as to why I thought I needed a square matrix so that perhaps you can see where I'm coming from. In each cell of the table contains the square root of the accumulated quantity bought by the buyer from the seller. Hence each time that the buyer buys from the seller again this new accumulated quantity will have to be recalculated. We thought that by using a square matrix we could easily query that cell, recalculate the data and pass that cell's data into a view file easily.